# Using CSS transform property to hover text over image

Tags: css, hover, transform

I'm using the `transform:translateY();`to hover text over two images.

The problem is that this method is not allowing me to position my text over specific parts of the images.

Ideally, I want to the freedom of being able to move the text more to the left, or to the right. At the moment I can only move the text up and down.

Alternatives method suggestions are always welcome.

Code is below and here is a [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZLdyL?editors=1100) -  ***(Hover the images with your screen full width as I haven't included media queries).***

**HTML**

```
<div class="projects">

          <div class="art-project1">
            <img class="img-img" src="https://static.standard.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2014/12/16/08/138188934.png" width="600" height="400" />
            <p class="project-description1">Get Involved</p>
          </div>

          <div class="art-project2">
            <img class="img-img" src="http://i.huffpost.com/gadgets/slideshows/343100/slide_343100_3557153_free.jpg" width="600"height="500" />
            <p class="project-description2">Be Apart</p>
          </div>
      </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
background-color:#f5f5dc;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

p { 
    color: #3232CD;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.projects {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
/* Images -------------------*/
.img-img {
    padding-top: 80px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.art-project1 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.art-project2 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: -20%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:10%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
}

.project-description1 {
    position:absolute;
    color: #3232CD;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transform:translateY(-1000%);
}
.art-project1:hover .project-description1 {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -o-transition:.5s;
  -ms-transition:.5s;
  -moz-transition:.5s;
  -webkit-transition:.5s;
  /* ...and now for the proper property */
  transition:.70s;
}

.project-description2 {
    position:absolute;
    color: #3232CD;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transform:translateY(-400%);
}

.art-project2:hover .project-description2 {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -o-transition:.5s;
  -ms-transition:.5s;
  -moz-transition:.5s;
  -webkit-transition:.5s;
  /* ...and now for the proper property */
  transition:.70s;
}
```

Comment: _"Ideally, I want to the freedom of being able to move the text more to the left, or to the right. At the moment I can only move the text up and down."_ - and have you tried to think about what the `Y` in `translateY` stands for for a second ...?

Comment: @CBroe Yes I have. Are you trying to help or just adding a condescending comment?

Comment: Well then what is your actual problem? Same as `translateY` allows you to “move” the element one the Y axis, `translateX` allows you to do the same thing on the X axis, or `translate` to work in both directions at the same time. If you knew that, then please explain how that does not work for you.

Comment: @CBroe Apologies - I was under the impression that only `translateY` or `translateX` would get the job done. I think I wasn't reading the tutorials properly. `translate` got the job done :)

Comment: Both versions get the job done - `transform` is one of those CSS properties that accept multiple values, so you can either do `transform: translate(…, …)` or `transform: translateX(…) translateY(…)`

Comment: @CBroe thank you. I'll take note for future use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `translate()` ;)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, I was under the impression that only `translateY()` or `translateX()`  
 would get the job done :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `position: absolute` on an element, you first need to give its parent container `position relative`. Then you can simply use the `top` and `left` (or `bottom` and `right` parameters to position the absolute element, with percentage or pixel values - no need for `transform: translate`at all (unless you need exact centering).

```css
body {
background-color:#f5f5dc;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

p { 
    color: #3232CD;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.projects {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
/* Images -------------------*/
.img-img {
    padding-top: 80px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.art-project1 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    left: 20%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}


.project-description1 {
    position:absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 6%;
    color: #3232CD;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
.art-project1:hover .project-description1 {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -o-transition:.5s;
  -ms-transition:.5s;
  -moz-transition:.5s;
  -webkit-transition:.5s;
  /* ...and now for the proper property */
  transition:.70s;
}

  -moz-transition:.5s;
  -webkit-transition:.5s;
  /* ...and now for the proper property */
  transition:.70s;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects">

          <div class="art-project1">
            <img class="img-img" src="https://static.standard.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2014/12/16/08/138188934.png" width="600" height="400" />
            <p class="project-description1">Get Involved</p>
          </div>
```